# Simple question on sudo su -

Tags: sudo

What is wrong with the following?

```
[cloudera@localhost zookeeper]$ sudo su - zookeeper
[cloudera@localhost zookeeper]$ whoami
cloudera
```

In response to one of the comments:

```
[cloudera@localhost zookeeper]$ cat /etc/passwd | grep zook
zookeeper:x:492:488:ZooKeeper:/var/run/zookeeper:/bin/false
[cloudera@localhost zookeeper]$ cat /etc/passwd | grep cloudera
cloudera-scm:x:497:498:Cloudera Manager:/var/run/cloudera-scm-server:/sbin/nologin
cloudera:x:500:500::/home/cloudera:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Do zookeeper and cloudera have the same numeric uid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to `su` to a user who's shell is [`/bin/false`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/false.1.html). `/bin/false` always exits with code 1, so you're never that user:

```
$ sudo su - dnsmasq
$ echo $?
1
```

If you want to start a shell with such a disabled user, use `sudo`:

```
$ sudo -u dnsmasq /bin/bash
$ whoami
dnsmasq
```

Note that `dnsmasq` usually has [`/sbin/nologin`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/nologin.8.html) (a politer version of `false`) as the shell, so the same principle applies.

Comment: oh nice catch. ooc i changed to /bin/bash - and then yes the sudo su - worked.

Comment: Yes, nice. I tested with a shell=/usr/sbin/nologin user (error is "This account is currently not available.") and a non-existent users (error is "No passwd entry for user 'nouser'") that had a clue to check passwd, maybe there should be an error message for /bin/false shells too

Comment: @Xen2050 That's the purpose of `nologin`, I'd say. The message that `nologin` delivers is customizable (on some systems) (hence no message in my answer), otherwise it works just like `false`.

Comment: So it is, didn't expect `nologin` to be an executable that just prints that line. So I could set a shell to /usr/games/fortune for a similar, fun effect. I wonder if having su give a message in such cases (especially with `false`) would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, `sudo su - [user]` seems to work here,

```
$ sudo su - jerk
jerk ~ $ whoami
jerk
```

even though the su manpage says that `-` should be the last option

```
       When - is used, it must be specified as the last su option. The other forms (-l
       and --login) do not have this restriction.
```

If I try that I get these errors, but it still works to login as [user]:

```
$ sudo su  [user] -
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

Does sudo work normally? Maybe it's not working...?

Comment: I suppose "last option" means last option argument (`su -m user -` would have `-m` and `-` as options, but `user` will be a non-option argument).

Comment: I think you're right there. Still a slightly confusing description.